# Wordpress website content is showing perfectly on mobile but is not showing on desktop

Tags: wordpress

I recently updated the site to the latest wordpress update and also updated all the plugins but the content is not showing on desktop. However the content is showing on mobile phone.
I am not sure what the problem really is or where to look for. The website is this https://www.sparleasing.com/

Answer (score 0):

It was mainly due to the deprecated jquery code on the theme file. I commented the code since it was if else code and default could be used.
Thank you.